# How to find which lists are symmetric/translated?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The figure below has 6 pictures from `a)` to `f)` which each depicts points `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` with point positions in 2 dimension. `a)` and `c)` shape like trapezoid, while `b)` and `d)` look like `V` character. Also, `e)` and `f)` have same point arrangement. I'd like to collect 3 groups:

```
(a, c)
(b, d)
(e, f)
```

```py
a = [
[[0.000, 0.500], [0.125, 0.250], [0.250, 0.000], [0.250, 0.500], [0.375, 0.250]],
[[0.000, 0.500], [0.125, 0.250], [0.250, 0.000], [0.375, 0.250], [0.500, 0.500]],
[[0.375, 0.250], [0.500, 0.000], [0.500, 0.500], [0.625, 0.250], [0.750, 0.500]],
[[0.375, 0.250], [0.500, 0.500], [0.625, 0.750], [0.750, 0.500], [0.875, 0.250]],
[[0.000, 0.000], [0.250, 0.500], [0.500, 0.000], [0.500, 0.500], [0.750, 0.500]],
[[0.125, 0.250], [0.375, 0.250], [0.375, 0.750], [0.625, 0.250], [0.875, 0.750]]
]
```

Output:

```py
[
[[0.000, 0.500], [0.125, 0.250], [0.250, 0.000], [0.250, 0.500], [0.375, 0.250]],
[[0.375, 0.250], [0.500, 0.000], [0.500, 0.500], [0.625, 0.250], [0.750, 0.500]]
]
================
[
[[0.000, 0.500], [0.125, 0.250], [0.250, 0.000], [0.375, 0.250], [0.500, 0.500]],
[[0.375, 0.250], [0.500, 0.500], [0.625, 0.750], [0.750, 0.500], [0.875, 0.250]]
]
================
[
[[0.000, 0.000], [0.250, 0.500], [0.500, 0.000], [0.500, 0.500], [0.750, 0.500]],
[[0.125, 0.250], [0.375, 0.250], [0.375, 0.750], [0.625, 0.250], [0.875, 0.750]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: So your input is pictures or data points? Also please look at [mcve]

Comment: @anishtain The pictures depict the data points. Please focus on data point only after you can imagine their arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

You can find your answer as following:

1. Define your lists
2. For each list, check if it matches any of the previous unique lists.
3. Each list has 4 possible mirrored versions (2 along x and 2 along
   y) so check all 4 of those

Step 1:

```
a = [[[0.000, 0.500], [0.125, 0.250], [0.250, 0.000], [0.250, 0.500], [0.375, 0.250]],
     [[0.000, 0.500], [0.125, 0.250], [0.250, 0.000], [0.375, 0.250], [0.500, 0.500]],
     [[0.375, 0.250], [0.500, 0.000], [0.500, 0.500], [0.625, 0.250], [0.750, 0.500]],
     [[0.375, 0.250], [0.500, 0.500], [0.625, 0.750], [0.750, 0.500], [0.875, 0.250]],
     [[0.000, 0.000], [0.250, 0.500], [0.500, 0.000], [0.500, 0.500], [0.750, 0.500]],
     [[0.125, 0.250], [0.375, 0.250], [0.375, 0.750], [0.625, 0.250], [0.875, 0.750]]]
```

Step 2:

```
graphs = []
for i in range(len(a)):
     matched = False
     for j in range(len(graphs)):
          if compare_mirrored_lists(graphs[j][0], a[i]):
               graphs[j].append(a[i])
               matched = True
               break
     if not matched:
          # If no matches were found, it's a new list and can be added
          graphs.append([a[i]])
```

Step 3:

```
def set_at_origin(lst):
    # Make sure the list will always have the same order
    lst = sorted(lst)
    # Make sure the first element is at [0, 0]
    return [[i[0] - lst[0][0], i[1] - lst[0][1]] for i in lst]

def compare_lists(a, b, error=0.001):
    # Check if a list of lists is the same
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            if abs(a[i][j] - b[i][j]) > error:
                return False
    return True

def compare_mirrored_lists(list_1, list_2):
    list_1 = set_at_origin(list_1)
    list_2 = set_at_origin(list_2)

    # Check all 4 mirrored options
    for mirror_x in [-1, 1]:
        for mirror_y in [-1, 1]:
            list_2_mirrored = [[mirror_x * i[0], mirror_y * i[1]] for i in list_2]
            list_2_mirrored = set_at_origin(list_2_mirrored)

            if compare_lists(list_1, list_2_mirrored):
                return True

    return False
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am just not clear what is the meaning of commands ```     if sum([1 for i in xs if i >= meanx]) > len(lst) // 2:
         max_x = lst[-1][0]
         lst = [[-(i[0] - max_x), i[1]] for i in lst] ```

Comment: @BinhThien I've implemented a much better approach which should have no uncovered edge cases. I also think it's much easier to intuitively understand